Not triggering the clear state timers in Apache Beam
I am posting the complete code here, since I have been trying it for days but no output yet
This is a popular code, which is explained by the Apache Beam team and is available on YT.
Here is the Link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpannyigCFg
I have modified the code to read the data from the SQS

import enum
import json
from typing import Optional, Iterable, List, NamedTuple

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam import PCollection, TimeDomain
from apache_beam import coders
from apache_beam.io.fileio import WriteToFiles
from apache_beam.io.textio import ReadFromText
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.transforms.userstate import ReadModifyWriteStateSpec, BagStateSpec, TimerSpec, \
    CombiningValueStateSpec, on_timer
from apache_beam.transforms.window import TimestampedValue
from apache_beam.utils.timestamp import Timestamp, Duration
from dateutil import parser
from apache_beam.io.textio import WriteToText
import boto3
from apache_beam import DoFn, ParDo, Map
import time
from datetime import datetime

SQS_QUEUE_URL = 'my_sqs_string'

class ReadFromSQS(DoFn):

    def __init__(self, queue_url):
        self.queue_url = queue_url
        
    def process(self, element):
        
        # Initialize AWS session with credentials
        self.session = boto3.Session(
            aws_access_key_id='access key',
            aws_secret_access_key='secret',
            region_name='us-east-1'
        )
        self.sqs_client = self.session.client('sqs')
        # sqs_client = boto3.client('sqs', region_name='us-east-1')  # Initialize the SQS client here
        """Continuously polls the SQS queue and yields messages."""
        while True:
            response = self.sqs_client.receive_message(
                QueueUrl=self.queue_url,
                MaxNumberOfMessages=10,
                WaitTimeSeconds=20  # Long polling
            )

            messages = response.get('Messages', [])

            if messages:
                for message in messages:
                    # print('$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ : ', message)
                    body = json.loads(message['Body'])
                    yield body  # Yield each message body

                    # Delete the message from the queue after processing
                    self.sqs_client.delete_message(
                        QueueUrl=self.queue_url,
                        ReceiptHandle=message['ReceiptHandle']
                    )
            else:
                print("No messages received, waiting...")
                time.sleep(5)  # Sleep to avoid rapid polling if no messages are available




# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Schema
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Great intro to Beam schemas in python: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zx4p-UNSmrA

# First we create a class that inherits from NamedTuple, this is our Schema
#
# To actually create an instance of TaxiPoint you can leverage dictionary unpacking
# Let's say you have a dictionary d = {"ride_id": asdf, ...,"passenger_count": 8}
# This dictionary's keys match the fields of TaxiPoint. 
# In this case, you use dictionary unpacking '**' to make class construction easy.
# Dictionary unpacking is when passing a dictionary to a function, 
# the key-value pairs can be unpacked into keyword arguments in a function call 
# where the dictionary keys match the parameter names of the function.
# So the call to the constructor looks like ==> TaxiPoint(**d)
class TaxiPoint(NamedTuple):
    ride_id: str
    point_idx: int
    latitude: float
    longitude: float
    timestamp: str
    meter_reading: float
    meter_increment: float
    ride_status: str
    passenger_count: int


class SessionReason(enum.Enum):
    DROPOFF_SEEN = 1
    GARBAGE_COLLECTION = 2


class TaxiSession(NamedTuple):
    ride_id: str
    duration: float
    start_timestamp: str
    end_timestamp: str
    n_points: int
    start_status: str
    end_status: str
    session_reason: SessionReason


# Second we let Beam know about our Schema by registering it
beam.coders.registry.register_coder(TaxiPoint, beam.coders.RowCoder)
beam.coders.registry.register_coder(TaxiSession, beam.coders.RowCoder)


# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Parsing functions
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def json_to_taxi_point(s: str) -> TaxiPoint:
    d: dict = json.loads(s)
    return TaxiPoint(**d)


def add_timestamp(p: TaxiPoint) -> TaxiPoint:
    ts: float = parser.parse(p.timestamp).timestamp()
    print('$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ ', p.timestamp, ts, TimestampedValue(p, ts))
    return TimestampedValue(p, ts)


def max_timestamp_combine(input_iterable):
    print(f"Input iterable: {input_iterable}")
    print(max(input_iterable, default=0))
    return max(input_iterable, default=0)


# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# TASK: Write a DoFn to find sessions using state & timers
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class FindSessions(beam.DoFn):
    """This DoFn applies state & timers to try to infer the session data from the received
    points."""

    # The state for the key
    KEY_STATE = ReadModifyWriteStateSpec('state', coders.StrUtf8Coder())

    # Elements bag of taxi ride events
    TAXI_RIDE_EVENTS_BAG = BagStateSpec('taxi_ride_events_bag',
                                        coders.registry.get_coder(TaxiPoint))

    # Event time timer for Garbage Collection
    GC_TIMER = TimerSpec('gc_timer', TimeDomain.WATERMARK)

    # The maximum element timestamp seen so far.
    MAX_TIMESTAMP = CombiningValueStateSpec('max_timestamp_seen', max_timestamp_combine)

    def process(self, element: tuple[str, TaxiPoint],
                element_timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam,
                key_state=beam.DoFn.StateParam(KEY_STATE),
                taxi_ride_events_bag=beam.DoFn.StateParam(TAXI_RIDE_EVENTS_BAG),
                max_timestamp_seen=beam.DoFn.StateParam(MAX_TIMESTAMP),
                gc_timer=beam.DoFn.TimerParam(GC_TIMER)
                # timer = beam.DoFn.TimerParam(GC_TIMER)
                ) -> Iterable[TaxiSession]:
        # TODO
        # Update the state for every new message
        key, point = element
        # print(f"Processing element {point}")
        if (key_state.read() is None) or (key_state.read() != key):
            key_state.write(key)
           
        taxi_ride_events_bag.add(point)
        max_timestamp_seen.add(element_timestamp.micros)
        print(f"Max timestamp seen: {max_timestamp_seen.read()}")
        print(f"element_timestamp: {element_timestamp}")
        # Check if end of session is seen, and emit the session data
        if point.ride_status == 'dropoff':
            
            print(f"Dropoff seen")
            #Session has ended
            session = self._calculate_session(key, taxi_ride_events_bag.read(), SessionReason.DROPOFF_SEEN)
            yield session
            # print(f"Session ended: {session}")
            taxi_ride_events_bag.clear()
            key_state.clear()
            max_timestamp_seen.clear()
            gc_timer.clear()
        else:
            
            print(f"Dropoff not seen")
            
          
            # gc_timer.set(expiration_ts)
            # Set the timer to expire 2 minutes after the current event timestamp
            expiration_seconds = element_timestamp.micros / 1_000_000 + 120  # Adding 120 seconds (2 minutes)
            expiration_ts = Timestamp(seconds=int(expiration_seconds))
            print(f"Setting timer for {expiration_ts}, expiration_seconds: {expiration_seconds}")
            # gc_timer.set(expiration_ts)
            print('********** ', Timestamp.now() + Duration(seconds=60))
            gc_timer.set(Timestamp.now() + Duration(seconds=100))

            
        

    @on_timer(GC_TIMER)
    def expiry_callback(
            self,
            key_state=beam.DoFn.StateParam(KEY_STATE),
            taxi_ride_events_bag=beam.DoFn.StateParam(TAXI_RIDE_EVENTS_BAG),
            max_timestamp_seen=beam.DoFn.StateParam(MAX_TIMESTAMP)) -> Iterable[TaxiSession]:
        
        # The timer has been triggered, you need to emit a session with whatever data has been
        # accumulated so far
        
        print(f"----------------------------Timer triggered-----------------------------")
        session = self._calculate_session(key_state.read(), taxi_ride_events_bag.read(), SessionReason.GARBAGE_COLLECTION)
        yield session
        taxi_ride_events_bag.clear()
        key_state.clear()
        max_timestamp_seen.clear()

    @staticmethod
    def _calculate_session(key: str,
                           taxi_ride_events_bag: Iterable[TaxiPoint],
                           session_reason: SessionReason) -> TaxiSession:
        # TODO
        # Since we emit sessions from two different methods, let's use the same function to emit
        # sessions, so we do it with consistency.
        
        points = list(taxi_ride_events_bag)
        points.sort(key=lambda x: x.timestamp)
        
        start_time = parser.parse(points[0].timestamp).timestamp()
        end_time = parser.parse(points[-1].timestamp).timestamp()
        
        print(f"Start time: {start_time}, End time: {end_time}")
        
        s = TaxiSession(
            ride_id=key,
            duration=end_time - start_time,
            start_timestamp=points[0].timestamp,
            end_timestamp=points[-1].timestamp,
            n_points=0,
            start_status=points[0].ride_status,
            end_status=points[-1].ride_status,
            session_reason=session_reason
        )
        
        print(f"\nSession: {s}\n")
        
        return s


@beam.ptransform_fn
def taxi_stats_transform(json_strs: PCollection[str]) -> PCollection[TaxiSession]:
    points: PCollection[TaxiPoint] = json_strs | "parse json strings" >> beam.Map(
        json_to_taxi_point)
    tstamp: PCollection[TaxiPoint] = points | "timestamping" >> beam.Map(add_timestamp)
    
    key: PCollection[tuple[str, TaxiPoint]] = tstamp | "key" >> beam.WithKeys(
        lambda e: e.ride_id)
    
    key | "Debug JSON Strings after timestamp" >> beam.Map(print)
    sessions: PCollection[TaxiSession] = key | "stats" >> beam.ParDo(FindSessions())
    sessions | "Debug JSON Strings" >> beam.Map(print)
    output: PCollection[TaxiSession] = sessions | "cep" >> beam.Filter(
        lambda s: s.duration > 1000)
    
    print("----------------Output: ", output)
    return output


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Pipeline
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# def run(beam_options: Optional[PipelineOptions] = None):
#     with beam.Pipeline(options=beam_options) as pipeline:
#         rides: PCollection[str] = pipeline | "Read ndjson input" >> ReadFromText(
#             file_pattern=beam_options.input_filename)
#         calculations: PCollection[TaxiSession] = rides | "calculations" >> taxi_stats_transform()
#         writeablecalculations: PCollection[str] = calculations | beam.Map(json.dumps)
#         writeablecalculations | WriteToFiles(path=beam_options.output_filename)


# def run(beam_options: Optional[PipelineOptions] = None):
#     with beam.Pipeline(options=beam_options) as pipeline:
#         # Read input
#         rides: PCollection[str] = pipeline | "Read ndjson input" >> ReadFromText(
#             file_pattern=beam_options.input_filename)
        
#         # Apply transformations
#         calculations: PCollection[TaxiSession] = rides | "calculations" >> taxi_stats_transform()
#         # Convert SessionReason enum to string for JSON serialization
#         calculations = calculations | "Convert SessionReason to string" >> beam.Map(
#             lambda session: session._replace(session_reason=session.session_reason.name)
#         )
#         # Convert to JSON strings
#         writeablecalculations: PCollection[str] = calculations | beam.Map(json.dumps)
        
#         # Debug: Output the JSON strings
#         writeablecalculations | "Debug JSON Strings" >> beam.Map(print)
        
#         # Write to output
#         writeablecalculations | "Write to output" >> beam.io.WriteToText(
#             file_path_prefix=beam_options.output_filename,
#             file_name_suffix=".json"
#         )
def run(beam_options: Optional[PipelineOptions] = None):
    with beam.Pipeline(options=beam_options) as pipeline:
        # Read input
        rides: PCollection[str] = pipeline | 'ReadFromSQS' >> beam.Create([None])
        
        rides: PCollection[str] = rides | 'ReadAccessLogs' >> ParDo(ReadFromSQS(SQS_QUEUE_URL))
        
        rides | "Debug JSON Strings" >> beam.Map(print)
        # Ensure the input is a JSON string before parsing
        rides = rides | "Convert to JSON String" >> beam.Map(json.dumps)
        # Apply transformations
        calculations: PCollection[TaxiSession] = rides | "calculations" >> taxi_stats_transform()
        # Convert SessionReason enum to string for JSON serialization
        calculations = calculations | "Convert SessionReason to string" >> beam.Map(
            lambda session: session._replace(session_reason=session.session_reason.name)
        )
        # Convert to JSON strings
        writeablecalculations: PCollection[str] = calculations | beam.Map(json.dumps)
        
        # Debug: Output the JSON strings
        # writeablecalculations | "Debug JSON Strings" >> beam.Map(print)
        
        # Write to output
        writeablecalculations | "Write to output" >> beam.io.WriteToText(
            file_path_prefix=beam_options.output_filename,
            file_name_suffix=".json"
        )

I am not getting any kind of error, but clear timer is not getting called, I am calling it after 100 seconds, so as expected it should call the clear timer function after 100 seconds and clear all the state, but it is not calling it.
And in the _calculate_session function it should print the Session but I guess code is not reaching till here and in stuck mode. SO what to do to clear the state and complete the whole process.
Please help me here to make it run.
I haven't removed the comments in case you need it.
